# Window socket programming with Python

Tags: python, sockets, window, ctypes, pywin32

I'm trying to implement Window socket using Python.

Mostly, everything has been so far solved using ctypes.windll.ws2_32 and pywin32 lib.

However, I haven't been able to find out how to translate the following C++ codes into Python and I wonder if anyone is kind enough to help:

```
LRESULT WINAPI AsyncSocketProc(
                           __in  HWND hwnd,
                           __in  UINT uMsg,
                           __in  WPARAM wParam,
                           __in  LPARAM lParam
                          )
switch(uMsg) {
    case WM_CREATE: 
        //...
    case WM_SOCKET: {# this is basically an int constant
        switch(WSAGETSELECTEVENT(lParam)){
              case FD_ACCEPT:
                  //accepting new conn
              case FD_READ:
                  //receiving data 
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I couldn't find Python's equivalent for WSAGETSELECTEVENT.

For the FD_ACCEPT, FD_READ, I could find them inside win32file package (of pywin32 lib)

Lastly, the reason why I'm trying to implement this Window socket programming is that the C++ version of the window socket server (above) is non-blocking for an application of mine but Python's built-in select.select is blocking. So I'm trying to see if I can port the C++ version to Python and see if it works.

EDITED: 
I would like to clarify that the socket server works as a 'plug in' to an existing **C++ program**, **which doesn't support threading**.

The socket server needs to **wait (indefinitely) for clients to connect** so it needs to continuously listen.
So using a normal Python socket or select.select **would entail a while loop** (or otherwise how can it acts as a server continuously listening for events? Please correct me I'm wrong), which would block the main program.

Somehow, using the Window Socket server callback above, the main program is not blocked. And this is the main reason while I'm trying to port it to Python.

The socket server is preferably in Python because many related libs the server needs are written in Python.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you use a zero timeout to `select.select` then it will not block.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you: this would make the select not blocking. However, for my purpose the server still blocks the main program as we need a while loop outside the select.select. I've edited my question to clarify my purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [socket module](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) instead. It already contains all the code you need to work with sockets without using the win32 API.

**[EDIT]** You can write multi threaded code that can handle several connections. Just accept the connection and then start a new thread, give it the connection and let it read the data in a `while 1: data = conn.recv(1024) ...` kind of loop.

That said, Python also has a module for just that: [SocketServer](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html)

**[EDIT2]** You say

> the socket server works as a 'plug in' to an existing program, which doesn't support threading.

It's a bit hard to help with so little information but think about it this way:

You can run the socket server loop in a new thread. This code is isolated from the rest of your app, so it doesn't matter whether the other code uses/supports threads. This solves your "endless loop" problem.

Now this socket server loop will get connections from clients. My guess is that the clients will call methods from the rest of the app and here, things get hairy.

You need a way to synchronize these calls. In other places (like all UI frameworks), there is a single thread which runs any UI calls (drawing something, creating the UI, responding to user input).

But if I understand you correctly, then you can in fact modify the "main loop" of the existing app and let it do more things (like listening to new connections). If you can do this, then there is a way out:

Create a new thread for the socket server as described above. When the server gets a connection, spawn a new thread that talks to the client. When the client sends commands, create "work objects" (see [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)) and put them into a [queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html).

In the main loop, you can look into the queue. If something is in there, pop the work objects and call it's `run()` method.

Comment: Thank you. The socket module is definitely good but it blocks the main program, which doesn't seem to support threading.

The while 1:
     data = conn.recv(1024)
     ...
The while 1 blocks my main program.

Comment: Set the sockets non-blocking if you don't want to block. And, of course, don't use a `while` loop like that.

Comment: You can have both blocking and non blocking read/writes with the regular socket methods. If you want to use blocking reads then you must use multi-threading/process, if you want to use non blocking read   you will need to use selec.select ot some other socket polling facility.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Thank you. Can you please clarify how to avoid the while loop for a server. I think we need it loops to be able to continuously listen for events?

Comment: @JoãoPinto. Thank you for your suggestion. the select.select can be non-blocking with timeout=0 but I still have the issue with the outer while loop, which I can't get rid of because it's a server. I've re-clarified my situation again in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need or want to port this code. This code is specific to how the WIN32 API notifies native code that a socket operation has completed. It doesn't apply in Python.

The equivalent in python would be, roughly, to paste the "accepting new conn" code in wherever your python code accepts a new connection. And paste the "receiving data" code wherever your python code receives data.

You can also use [select](http://docs.python.org/howto/sockets.html), just keep in mind that the semantics are a bit of the reverse of async sockets. With async sockets, you start an operation whenever you want and you get a callback when it completes. With 'select', it tell you when to perform an operation such that it completes immediately.

Comment: Thank you. According you explanation, it appears that Window's Async socket is what I actually need. Is there any way to implement it in Python?